# Multiresolution Modifier - Lost of details

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

Blender Version 2.79

Problem:

1. With a multiresolution on, when switching between Sculpt and Object 
   Mode, the vertices displayed are **different**.
2. When the Multiresolution is **applied**, the object is not
   subdivided in Edit mode neither is Object mode. Therefore, the
   lack of vertices in Object mode resulting in the lost of fine
   details such as pores and wrinkles on a character.

Additional Info:

- No other active modifier is on.
- Suspecting some settings are tweaked accidentally, as it works when appending the same mesh to a newly create blendfile.
- Ensured the Level of Sculpt, Preview and Render is at the same level.
- Below attached a sample of sundivided cube with same problem, please feel free to take a look.

https://jp410-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mac281_office2016_club/EdbYYnvCs-xEqiE7ZZzgOrcBUnIgrn0w7t6wvaT_A4qRXQ?e=AkVeWv [98mb]

Comment: do you have any other modifiers on the same object? You might need to apply those modifiers before you apply the multires one.

Comment: No I don't have.